# why am I getting spaces in sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/g'

Tags: regex, sed

I want to  add parenthesis to all words
I used

```
sed 's/[a-z]*/(&)/g'
```

inputfile.txt

```
hola crayola123456
abc123456
```

however I am selecting all the spaces

```
(hola) (crayola)1()2()3()4()5()6()
(abc)1()2()3()4()5()6()
```

shouldn't I be getting only the words?
I am using mac sed

thanks

Comment: Use: `sed -E 's/[a-z]+/(&)/g'` on OSX, `[a-z]*` will match empty text also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a regex that can match an empty string. `[a-z]*` can match any empty space before a char since regex "sees" (i.e. checks) these positions. You need to replace the `*` (matching *zero* or more occurrences) with `+` quantifier (to match *one* or more characters).

Here is an example of how this can be implemented in GNU sed:

```
echo "hola crayola123456" | sed 's/[a-z]\+/(&)/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/g55xO9)

On Mac, as per [anubhava's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168490/why-am-i-getting-spaces-in-sed-s-a-z-g/39168584?noredirect=1#comment65679355_39168490), you need to use `E` option and use an unescaped `+`:

```
echo "hola crayola123456" | sed -E 's/[a-z]+/(&)/g'
```

Comment: OSX sed doesn't allow `\+`, see my comment below question.

Comment: just use `+`. Any sed implementation is different in quoting.

Comment: Certainly, escaping rules with various options/OSes will differ. The snippet is only an example of how it works in GNU sed. The solution is expressed in words *You need to replace the `*` (matching zero or more occurrences) with `+` quantifier (to match one or more characters)*.

Comment: @anubhava '\+' works but means the "plus sign" itself, not "at least one match"

Answer (score 1):

Two *errors*:

1. `*` means 0 or more matches, you need at least one match, then `+`;
2. `sed` (OSX version) uses basic regexp by default (so `+` isn't available), you should activate *extended regexp syntax* with option `-E`.

Then:

```
echo "hola abc1234 foo12 bar" | sed -E 's/[a-z]+/(&)/g'
```

produces:

```
(hola) (abc)1234 (foo)12 (bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually sed is quite inconsistent in handling matches. From pure regex theory I would tell that any sequence `[a-z]*` in the line should emit the `(&)`, so the theoretical perfect result would be `(hola)() (crayola)()1()2()3()4()5()6`, imho: First match [a-z]* hola, then match [a-z]* as the empty string for the next char , as  did not match it will be echoed ... and so on...

The Plan9 sed for example emits `(hola)() (crayola)()1()2()3()4()5()6`.

What the Linux and BSD/Mac sed do here is quite strange. You can see the effect if you compare `"hola1"` with `"hola1a"`: `(hola)1()` and `(hola)1(a)`.